# Basic CSS Menu Not Working -- Something is Conflicting?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I'm not doing anything fancy.  And I've double and triple checked my code and tried various things.  I have no idea why the dropdown is getting cut off.  What is going on here?

http://nbkclientsite.fuzzpopstudio.com/

Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: we cannot magically spot the problem. some code or a fiddle would go a long way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have `overflow:hidden` on your `menu-themainmenu-container` remove that and it works.

Comment: Thanks folks.  I knew it had to be something stupid simple.  Sometimes you just get in the weeds and miss the problem.  I appreciate the fresh eyes!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked you z-index for the drop down and the container that is overlapping it? I don't have access to a decent browser ATM, at my 'day' job... but it looks like the z-index is simply off.

Comment: Its fixed.  it was the overflow problem.  I was messed up and not looking high enough in the DOM.  Thanks!